# Executable app pcloud

Tags: appimage, pcloud

I have problem installing pcloud on ubuntu 22.04. As usuall, any any other distro or previous ubuntus, I'dd download the pcloud file, (application/vnd.appimage), and right click on the file, go to properties, and mark the make it executable, and then then execute or just doble clik it and in seconds it would open the pcloud. But now its not working.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

Update apt database with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After updating apt database - install libfuse2 using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libfuse2
```

And run (double click) `pcloud` (first you must gave Properties - Permissions for Execute)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution cause i was stuck in the same thing. You should install libfuse2 to make all appimage works. Now I can use pcloud.
Hope to help